Why was Gwen trying to stop Pavitr here?
Despite the Spider-Gang’s attempts to pull him away with a web,
Spot was intentionally sucked into the super-collider, after which
the super-collider disappeared into thin air with a sudden silence:

Pavitr: Well, that was another easy adventure for Spider-Man.
Gwen: No-no-no-no-no-no-no-no! No-no-no-no-no!

Why was Gwen trying to stop Pavitr here?

The Spider Crew are trying to tell him that things aren't over. They're about to get much much worse.
Gwen, Hobie and Miles were probably worried that Pavitr was going to do something really dumb, like webbing over to the Collider to have a good look at it, but the explosion happened almost immediately afterwards anyway.

In the original script it was actually funnier. He was corrected mid-senten---.

PAVITR: Well that was another easy adventure for Spider-Ma--
KRAKOOOMMMM!!!!!!!
THE ROOM IS LEVELED IN A BRILLIANT EXPLOSION OF DARK ENERGY.
Everyone hits the floor as BLACK KIRBY DOTS flow from Spot’s blazing silhouette...
... and throw MILES

